# Setting PATH ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, ionic-framework, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

I have obstacle when run sudo ionc build android.

Error log terminal:

[image]

Set enviroment varibale  in .profile:

[image]

Please give me solutions.  How to setting PATH that true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is not able to find the environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` in your .bashrc file. To resolve this error, you need to add the following to line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="<path/to/your/sdk/without/quotes>"
```

For me, I added the following

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/chi6rag/Library/Android/sdk"
```

And ran `source ~/.bashrc` so that the configuration is loaded.